# Epsilon Delta proof for a limit

Tags: limits

Give an epsilon-delta proof that the limit for x→0 of x³sin(x) exists.

What I can derive from this question is

lim = ?= 0 
x=0

so, with an epsilon delta proof, i have to proof that at point x=0 there is a limit. So x³ isn't possible for x<0.

Because of de sin(x) I get that it is not possible to have a negative x, but I don;t know how to use the epsilon delta proof with this.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you tried, but the idea is as follows :

You begin by choosing a "tolerance" $\epsilon > 0$, then you want to make
$$
|x^3\sin(x)| < \epsilon
$$
Now we know that $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$, so it suffices to force $|x^3| < \epsilon$.

How do I do this? Well, if I make $|x| < \epsilon^{1/3}$ of course!

So I take $\delta = \epsilon^{1/3}$ and everything is wonderful.

Comment: To take the cube root for any given real number (in this case $\epsilon$) you have to know it exists. But the proof of that requires continuity of the function $f(x) = x^3$ which depends on proving the limit $\lim_{x \to a} x^3 = a^3$. But in this problem we are essentially proving the special case for $a = 0$. So to be fully rigorous I think we should assume the above limit is not proven and hence assume we don't know that cube roots exist for all real numbers. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar : Yes, but proving $x \mapsto x^n$ is continuous is usually done using the algebra of limits (if $f$ and $g$ continuous, then $fg$ continuous, etc.). Proving all the rigourously is probably best left for another time.

Comment: Yes. That's true. It can be done some other time.

Comment: @CameronBuie It's easy to see $f$ is 1 to 1 since it's increasing. But how would you show $f$ is onto without using continuity? In Spivak's Calculus, he said the same thing but for $x^2$. He said, to show that square roots exist for all real number, you need to use the intermediate value theorem (by continuity) to show that for any $c$, there is $x$ so that $x^2 = c$. This essentially showing that $x^2$ is onto and hence it is invertible on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar: That's an excellent point, actually. The typical proof would require Intermediate Value Theorem. I feel like we should be able to get around that somehow by using Dedekind cuts, but I'm not sure. I'll have to think on it.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar: Upon further consideration, the proof by Dedekind cuts is effectively a proof of continuity, so we really don't save ourselves any effort, there. An easy fix to this proof, at any rate, is to find a positive integer $n$ such that $\dfrac1{n^3}\le\epsilon,$ and then take $\delta=\dfrac1n.$

Answer (score 1):

We want to show the limit is 0. So we have to show for any given $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ to get $|x^3 \sin(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$.

The general idea is that $\sin(x)$ is bounded and it is easy to show $x^3 \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. More precisely, $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$. So $|x^3 \sin(x)| \leq |x|^3$.

Now, for any given $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon) > 0$, you will see why in the next step. So if $0 < |x| < \delta$, then since $\delta \leq 1$ we have $|x| < 1 \implies |x|^2 < 1 \implies |x|^3 < |x| < \delta \leq \epsilon$. But using the inequality in the first paragraph, we have $|x^3 \sin(x)| \leq |x|^3 < \epsilon$.

So what we have shown is for any given $\epsilon > 0$, we can take $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon)$ to get $|x^3 \sin(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$. This is precisely the definition of limits with the limit being $0$.